# Работа метода в другом потоке

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Доброго времени суток. Есть метод, который срабатывает при запуске приложения:

```
void loadFile() throws IOException {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = am.open("text.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.equals("===")){
                arr_full.add(toarr);
                toarr = "";
            }else {
                toarr = toarr.concat(line).concat("\n");
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    }
```

Т.к файл великоват (3.89 мб), запуск приложения затягивается до 3-5 сек. Подскажите пожалуйста, как выполнить данный метод в другом потоке, чтобы основной UI поток запускался без задержек. Спасибо.

**UPD**

**MyApp.java**

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyApp extends Application {

    String line;
    String toarr = "";
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_full = new ArrayList<>();
    int i, j, page;
    LoadFile lf;

    void loadFile() throws IOException {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = am.open("text.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.equals("===")){
                arr_full.add(toarr);
                toarr = "";
            }else {
                toarr = toarr.concat(line).concat("\n");
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        MySingleton.initInstance();
        if(MySingleton.getArr().size() == 0){
            lf = new LoadFile();
            lf.execute();
        }
    }

    class LoadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                loadFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            MySingleton.setArr(arr_full);
        }
    }
}
```

Лог

```
08-22 20:16:34.107 518-518/com.app.app D/myLogs: запуск onPreExecute чтения файла
08-22 20:16:34.117 518-558/com.app.app D/myLogs: запуск doInBackground чтения файла
08-22 20:16:34.985 518-518/com.app.app D/myLogs: запуск onPreExexute парсера
08-22 20:16:37.862 518-518/com.app.app D/myLogs: запуск onPostExecute чтения файла
08-22 20:16:39.971 518-676/com.app.app D/myLogs: запуск doInBackground парсера
08-22 20:16:40.785 518-518/com.app.app D/myLogs: запуск onPostExecute парсера
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете выполнять фоновую работу с помощью `AsyncTask`, `IntentService`, `Service`. Ниже я привел пример класса наследника `AsyncTask` который в методе `doInBackground` может выполнять фоновую работу. Если вам этот вариант по какой то причине не подходит - могу добавить в ответ вариант с `IntentService` или `Service`

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      AssetManager am = getAssets();
      InputStream inputStream = am.open("text.txt");
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.equals("===")){
            arr_full.add(toarr);
            toarr = "";
        }else {
            toarr = toarr.concat(line).concat("\n");
        }
    }
    reader.close();
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      tvInfo.setText("End");
    }
  }
}
```

и вызвать его можно так:

```
new MyTask.execute();
```

---

Пример `IntentService` из [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

При старте сервиса - кидаем в него `Intent` с экшеном. В сервисе он попадет в метод  `onHandleIntent()` в нем вы можете по экшену определить, что нужно сделать(вызвать какой то метод). Каждый такой `Intent` запускает новый поток, который будет закрыт после того, как ваш код отработает.

```
*
 * Creates a new Intent to start the RSSPullService
 * IntentService. Passes a URI in the
 * Intent's "data" field.
 */
mServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), RSSPullService.class);
mServiceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(dataUrl));
mServiceIntent.setAction("YOUR_ACTION");

// Starts the IntentService
getActivity().startService(mServiceIntent);
```

**RSSPullService.java**

```
public class RSSPullService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        //достаем action
        String action = intent.getAction();

        ...

        // достаем  данные из интента
        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
        ...

        switch(action){
           case "YOUR_ACTION":
               //сделать что то там...
        }

    }
}
```

И не забыть прописать сервис в **Manifest.xml**

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
     ...
     <!--
         Because android:exported is set to "false",
         the service is only available to this app.
     -->
     <service
          android:name=".RSSPullService"
          android:exported="false"/>
      ...
<application/>
```

---

Пример `Service` детально описан в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) 
я код оттуда копировать не буду, стоит отметь только что основное отличие от `IntentService` в том, что  управлять жизненным циклом сервиса нужно самостоятельно, в том смысле что  запустив сервис сам он не остановиться.

Comment: `AsyncTask` впринципе подходит, но у меня в приложении уже есть один `AsyncTask` для работы с интернетом. Сейчас добавил второй `AsyncTask` для загрузки файла и складывается ощущение, что второй(для интернета) не запускается, пока не отработает первый(загрузка файла).

Comment: По-идеии такого быть не должно, так как само название AsyncTask говорит о том что эти задачи асинхронный, но точно без примера кода сказать не могу!

Comment: Код очень большой, поэтому приведу основные моменты. В приложении использую класс синглтон, который запускается через `MyApp.java` (для того, чтобы синглтон не уничтожался от смены активити. Обновил первый пост). В `MyApp.java` добавил `AsyncTask`, в котором грузится файл и добавляется в синглтон. В `MainActivity` в `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` запускается второй `AsyncTask` и там отрабатывает библиотека `Jsoup`, которая парсит данные сайта ...//

Comment: //... Возможно, что когда грузится файл, этот метод `loadFile()` "кушает" много ресурсов смартфона, вследствие чего и второй `AsyncTask` кажется, что грузится дольше. Но это я так предполагаю)

Comment: Попробуйте проставить логи в обоих асинтасках в методах onPreExecute, doInBackground, onPostExecute и посмотреть что когда вызываеться

Comment: Обновил первый пост. Разница между `onPreExexute` и `doInBackground` парсера 5 секунд, что весьма странно...

Comment: Ну как вы видите задачи выполняются параллельно,значит искать проблему нужно в методе в котором парсите, если это проблема вообще существует, может оно просто долго загружает и парсит всего-навсего.

Comment: Возможно. Не могли бы Вы привести пример с `IntentService` и `Service`? С ними не сталкивался. И я буду знать и может кому то пригодится, помечу как ответ. Кстати, запустил без загрузки файла, разница между `onPreExexute` и `doInBackground` парсера составила 2.5 сек.

Comment: Возможно, действительно, ресурсы смартфона каким то образом распределяются на задача.Варианты с  IntentService и Service немного поже добавлю в ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! И, если не затруднит, укажите отличия между ними, чтобы знать в каких ситуациях применять.

Comment: @Pollux окей, без проблем